# PHP rewrite array to string,

Tags: php, arrays, yii, explode, implode

in this case, for example, 
 i have string from array of person_code => 1,2,3 
 then i want change that string to another string from array of person_nama => name1, name2, name3

 i have try with my code :

```
public function Person_name($person_code)
    {
        $code= explode(',', $person_code);
        $name=array();
        for($i=0; $i<count($code); $i++){
            $sql= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select nm_person from tbl_person where kd_person="'.$code[$i].'";');
            $name=$sql->queryRow();
        }
        $namearray= implode(',',$name);
        return $namaarray;
    }
```

but that result is only return the last person name in array, 
anyone can help me?? thank you

Comment: you're overwriting it, `$name[] =`, push continually, and why not just use a `WHERE IN` clause, i'm sure `Yii` already has that somewhere, use the API, that accepts a `WHERE IN` clause method and also that accepts an array of integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just answer this by just using a band-aid solution with just normally pushing the results into the array. Your current code is just overwriting `$name`.

```
$name[] = $sql->queryRow();
```

But.

Don't directly interpolate variables into the query string. Just stop that, you're already using a good framework with useful query builder.

Instead of executing each query for each id, why not use a `WHERE IN` clause flavor along with the builder.

Much better untested basic idea:

```
public function Person_name($person_code)
{
    $persons = array();
    $person_code = explode(',', $person_code);

    if(!empty($person_code)) {
        $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)
        ->select('nm_person')
        ->from('tbl_person')
        ->where(array('IN', 'kd_person', $person_code)
        ->queryAll();

        $persons = implode(', ', $result);
    }

    return $persons;
}
```

Based on reading the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder)

Comment: thank you for response, that is good idea, i have try your code, but any error in Array Helper.php, i think that is because i use Yii 1.xx

Comment: @YanuarIhsan oh okay thats why, i've changed it into that version you're using, i'v eedited it

Comment: @YanuarIhsan sure glad this helped